# How to index a wide table of booleans

Tags: mysql, indexing, booleanquery

My question is on building indexes when your client is using a lot of little fields.

Consider a search of the following:
(can't change it, this is what the client is providing)

```
SKU zone1   zone2   zone3   zone4   zone5   zone6   zone7   zone8   zone9   zone10  zone11
A123                1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1   
B234                1       1       1       1       1       1       1       
C345                        1       1       1       1       1       1
```

But it is much wider, and there are many more categories than just Zone.
The user will be looking for skus that match at least one of the selected zones. I intend to query this with (if the user checked "zone2, zone4, zone6")

```
select SKU from TABLE1 where (1 IN (zone2,zone4,zone6))
```

Is there any advantage to indexing with a multi tiered index like so:

```
create index zones on table1 (zone1,zone2,zone3,zone4,zone5,zone6,zone7,zone8,zone9,zone10,zone11)
```

Or will that only be beneficial when the user checked zone1?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: An index on boolean fields is a waste of time, as there are only two possible values that every row will fit. In addition, your *multi tiered index* will only work if you're searching for column content in the *exact order* of columns, which means that a search would have to be on zone1 first, adding zone2, then adding zone3; the index would be useless if you were searching for content in zone5 without having 1,2,3, and 4 (in that order) as well.

Comment: Agree with @KenWhite. The only real way to optimize this is to redesign it. Maybe you could add another table that's designed better, and use a trigger to keep it in sync with this table.

Comment: It's sad you can't redesign it, because you'd be much better off with a more normalized table, where you had a column for `sku` and `zones`, where you could have multiple rows for a sku (one for each zone it has), which would then allow a useful index. With a wide row, an index won't be of any benefit other than locating a sku; the rest is simply not able to be optimized.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite and Barmar. It was driving me crazy that I couldn't think of the right way to index it.  At least now I can stop wondering.

Comment: @KenWhite How about a filtered index? Is that supported in MySQL?

Comment: @DavidG: I don't know, but with boolean (bit) fields it's not going to help anyway, as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @KenWhite You're right. It would help if OP only cared about a single zone. Anyway, I've just checked and it seems it's not possible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should structure the data as:

```
create table SKuZones (
    Sku int not null,
    zone varchar(255)
)
```

It would be populated with the places where a SKU has a 1.  This can then take great advantage of an index on `SKUZones(zone)` for an index.  A query such as:

```
select SKU
from SKUZones
where zone in ('zone2', 'zone4', 'zone6');
```

will readily take advantage of an index.  However, if the data is not structured in a way appropriate for a relational database, then it is much harder to make queries efficient.

One approach you could take if you can add a column to the table is the following:

- Add a new column called `zones` or something similar.
- Use a trigger to populate it with values for each "1" in the columns (so "zone3 zone4 zone5 . . ." for the first row in your data).
- Build a full text index on the column.
- Run your query using `match against`

Answer (score 0):

Indexing boolean values is almost always useless.

What if you use a `SET` datatype?  Or `BIGINT UNSIGNED`?

Let's talk through how to do it with some sized INT, named `zones`

zone1 is the bottom bit (1<<0 = 1)
zone2 is the next bit (1<<1 = 2)
zone3 is the next bit (1<<2 = 4)
zone4 is the next bit (1<<3 = 8)
etc.

`where (1 IN (zone2,zone4,zone6))` becomes
`where (zones & 42) != 0`.

To check for all 3 zones being set:  `where (zones & 42) = 42`.

As for indexing, no index will help this design; there will still be a table scan.

If there are 11 zones, then `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes) will suffice.  This will be considerably more compact than other designs, hence possibly faster.

For *this* query, you can have a "covering" index, which helps some:
`select SKU from TABLE1 where (zones & 42) != 0` .. `INDEX(zones, SKU)`

(Edit)

42 = 32 | 8 | 2 = zone6 | zone4 | zone2 -- where `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html

`(zones & 42) = 42` effectively checks that all 3 of those bits are "on".
`(zones & 42) = 0` effectively checks that all 3 of those bits are "off".
In both cases, it is ignoring the other bits.

42 could be represented as `((1<<5) | (1<<3) | (1<<1))`.  Because of precedence rules, I recommend using more parentheses than you might think necessary.

`1 << 5` means "shift" `1` by `5` bits.

Comment: Yes, SET was my original design and I think it would have worked nicely. 
Could you please elaborate on the condition:  

    where (zones & 42) = 42;  Since the ampersand is not an operator, I'm not sure what this conditional does.

How does that work?